# GRASS GIS: How to generate large DEM from contours; elevation points and coastline mask

Tags: gis

I need to generate a DEM (10m Cell Size) of the entire coastline for South Africa. I've tried to generate it within ArcGIS, but the Annudem Algorithm that ESRI is currently using within Top To Raster is not capable of generating my DEM.

Please can anyone let me know firstly if GRASS GIS can handle DEM's this large (i.e. millions of cells) and can use shapefiles: Contours; PointElevation and Coastline Mask.

Can anyone give me the necessary steps required to accomplish the following within GRASS GIS.

Please note that I've never used GRASS before.

Regards

Peter Wilson

Answer (score 1):

Grass GIS CAN handle large DEM`s though I am not 100% sure about so huge territory. I can suggest you to divide all territory in subregions and process them separately and later on make mosaic using **r.patch**

In short, here is how I`d do.

All commands you can either find in GUI or launch writing them in console.

1. Prepare/Set up location and coordinate system for your desired place, e.g. South Africa
2. Upload your vector files using **v.in.ogr** . You can use GUI.
3. Upload your mask file.
4. Load uploaded vector file in map view display and right click in map list display and choose - set region from display (or something similar)
5. Use **g.region** and set your resolution (res=10) (actually here also you can set region from loaded raster or vector map)
6. If your mask is in vector format, convert it to raster file using **v.to.rast** giving any masking value, 1 or 9999 for example. You can use GUI.
7. Set the mask with **r.mask** and define previously set value. This is where I suggest to use console but I guess GUI also could work out well.
8. If you have multiple vector maps (points, lines) with values, you have to join them in one composite vector map using **v.patch**, but before doing it...
9. make sure all of them have equal column name where values are stored. If neccessary, for each loaded vector map rename column in which you have your values using **v.db.renamecol**. Now you can launch **v.patch** with *"copy also attribute table"* option so now you have composite vector map *altogether* which you`ll use for DEM generation.
10. Now all pre-works are done and continue with **r.surf.rst** or **r.surf.idw** or **any other** algorithm which takes values from specified column in your patched *altogether* vector map and generates that DEM.

[Here you can find](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM) some specs about each DEM generation algorythm